# JApplet open new window when click on jButton3

Tags: java, swing, applet

this is my Applet so far, i can´t figure out how to open a new window (JFrame), when i click on "Register" JButton, i want to open a new window "Register Form Window" is to register all users (User Name, User Password, Age, etc).

LogIn.java

```
package intranetmailingsystem;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class LogIn extends javax.swing.JApplet{

    @Override
    public void init() {
        try {
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(this::initComponents);
        } catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Intranet Mailing System");

        jLabel2.setText("User name");

        jLabel3.setText("Password");

        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText("LogIn");

        jButton2.setText("Clear");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("Register");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 75, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1)
                            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 128, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(53, 53, 53)
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addGap(48, 48, 48)
                            .addComponent(jButton2)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton3))
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(68, 68, 68)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 283, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addContainerGap(49, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 64, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton3))
                .addGap(65, 65, 65))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      // need to add some code here !

    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        {
            jTextField1.setText("");
            jTextField2.setText("");
        }
    }                                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private void dispose() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

InternetMailingSystem.java  :

```
package intranetmailingsystem;

    public class IntranetMailingSystem 
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            // TODO code application logic here
        }   
    }
```

Please check this:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHeDJ.png)

Comment: Got it !!!, i just added this line: new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);

Comment: [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free)

Comment: @insyspower You might find that your solution works on your machine, but applets have a very tight security model which may prevent it from showing the window

Answer (score 0):

You have to create another window. So if you create another JFrame class call Register you would add this in your code.

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      Register menu = new Register();
      menu.setVisible(true);



   }
```